# VS 2010 C++ creating library

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I would like to develop a game. Now i just want to make the engine. Im considering using SFML and C++ to do this, but this question is not about it.

I want to separate  game from engine.
So at first, I made solution with C++ project into it. So far so good.

Then i added new project to this solution. HERE my question begins.

What settings do i need to change in engine project, so it compiles as library ? (.dll i guess ?)

And what settings do i need to change in game project (.exe) so i can access classes from engine library ?

School didn't taught me, how to do this. In C# its easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MFC then ,you need to create a DLL for your game engine by using the Wizard Vc++->MFC->MFC DLL.

if it is win32 dll or simply a c++ dll you need to create win32 project. Please read the following posts to understand each one of it

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6351/Regular-DLL-Tutor-For-Beginners

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2516/Creating-and-consuming-MFC-DLLs-for-Beginners

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8341/DLLs-are-simple-Part-2

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8417/DLLs-are-Simple-Part-3